# Reproduce timer picker in the clock app – SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, picker

I want to recreate the picker with multiple components just like in the clock app

[image]

I want to achieve the same effect of the hours and seconds being a little off axis (notice that the selected value in `seconds` is a little offset to the right compared to the numbers in the list)

I've tried to use a `GeometryReader` but I had no success, and ended up with a messy UI.

Simply using a `HStack` with three pickers inside (one for hours, another for minutes and the third for seconds) wasn't enough to achieve the same effect

Comment: It is almost impossible to build what you want with Picker that already exist in UIKit or SwiftUI, you have to think about making a custom Picker. then starting this project.

Comment: Oh, that's sad to hear. I supposed it would be simple, since Apple has it implemented in their own apps. But thanks to your comment! I'll follow the path of implementing it!